# Specific key mapping in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I configure Vim to set

```
"require 'pry'; binding.pry"
```

in Ruby and

```
"debugger;"
```

in JavaScript when pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> via key mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this in your `.vimrc` as follows:

```
autocmd FileType ruby map <F2> orequire 'pry'; binding.pry<ESC>
autocmd FileType javascript map <F2> odebugger;<ESC>
```

When the <kbd>F2</kbd> key is pressed in a `*.rb` file, "require pry" will be set and "debugger" is set in a `*.js` file.

Comment: You're creating global mappings, so if you edit Ruby and then split a window with a JS file, that will override the mapping. Use `map <buffer> <F2> ...` instead to create a buffer-local mapping. Furthermore, best practice to use `nnoremap` instead, non-recursive and restricted to normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct, but not completely correct. You should use the `noremap` variant of `map` (see `:h noremap`), and the proper `noremap` for whatever mode your are in. If that's insert mode, then it's `inoremap <F2> require...`, or `nnoremap` for normal mode, etc.

You can also put those mappings into their own file instead of your vimrc so that you don't need to use autocommands (see `:h ftplugin`). And (thanks to the comments for reminding me) use `<buffer>` mappings so they only apply to the file you set them on (see `:h <buffer>`). In all, this is a good setup for you:

In `~/vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`, put the line:

`inoremap <buffer> <F2> require 'pry'; binding.pry`

and in `~/vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`, put the line:

`inoremap <buffer> <F2> defbugger;`

On windows, the `vim` directory is instead the `vimfiles` directory. If you want those mappings in normal mode instead of insert mode, you need to put `i` or `O` or another character like that at the front to go into insert mode and put `<Esc>` on the end to exit insert mode.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the better answer! But you should still use `<buffer>` mappings, otherwise the last filetype you open will overwrite your previous mappings. See [`:help :map-local`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local).

Comment: `:h ftplugin` also mentions that explicitly: *"To make sure mappings will only work in the current buffer use the `map <buffer>` command."*